# Do a query to an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this:

```
$array = array(1 => array('min' => 0, 'max' => 0.5, 'value'=>12.5),
2 => array('min' => 0.5, 'max' => 1, 'value'=>13.5),
3 => array('min' => 1, 'max' => 1.5, 'value'=>15.5),
4 => array('min' => 1.5, 'max' => 2, 'value'=>18.5));
```

Then I have the variable (which of course is dynamic)

```
$number= 1.1;
```

How would I do to get the value 15.5 given that `$number` is between `1` and `1.5` ?

Comment: Just curious, but what should happen with edge cases? If `$number` is 0.5, should it return 12.5, or 13.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through the array.

```
function getValue($array, $number){
  foreach($array as $params):
    if($params['min'] < $number and $params['max'] > $number)
      return $params['value'];
  endforeach;
}
```

Comment: Only thing I would change is on either the > or on the <, you need to make one of them >= or <=. Otherwise if .5 is put in nothing will get returned.

Answer (score 1):

Overcomplicated map-reduce way:

http://codepad.org/s6T86VYf

```
$array = array(
1 => array('min' => 0, 'max' => 0.5, 'value'=>12.5),
2 => array('min' => 0.5, 'max' => 1, 'value'=>13.5),
3 => array('min' => 1, 'max' => 1.5, 'value'=>15.5),
4 => array('min' => 1.5, 'max' => 2, 'value'=>18.5));

$number= 1.1;

function reduce( $row ){
  global $number;
  return $row['min'] <= $number
      && $row['max'] >= $number;
}

function map( $row ){
  return $row['value'];
}

$reduced = array_filter( $array, 'reduce');

$mapped = array_map('map', $reduced );

print_r( $mapped );
```